# how to create website without html and css

Tags: html, web

I think html and css is terrible.
How can I create a website without html and css?

like android

```
<LinearLayout>something</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use frameworks or softwares that allow u to create websites by using drag and drop :)

Comment: I don't want to drag and drop :) ,I just want to create my website without the Historical issues . Sometimes I feel html and css so ugly

Comment: Then you might as well tell me a way to fly without using any aid :)

Comment: It's not impossible. You would have to reinvent a standard from scratch, and have all browsers (or new browsers) implement your standard. Get in touch with W3. [Here is the link to get you started.](https://www.w3.org/standards/)

Answer (score 5):

HTML is the standard for generating content on the web. From Wikipedia:

> HyperText Markup Language, commonly referred to as HTML, is the
>   standard markup language used to create web pages. Along with CSS, and
>   JavaScript, HTML is a cornerstone technology, used by most websites to
>   create visually engaging webpages, user interfaces for web
>   applications, and user interfaces for many mobile applications.[1](https://webassembly.org/) Web
>   browsers can read HTML files and render them into visible or audible
>   web pages. HTML describes the structure of a website semantically
>   along with cues for presentation, making it a markup language, rather
>   than a programming language.

Even if the android markup-style may have some advantages I would strongly advice you to reconsider using HTML/css/javascript when creating web-content. They are the only languages that all the major web browsers natively understand.

However, if you really don't want to use HTML I suggest Flash or Silverlight. Silverlight uses a variant of WPF for it's markup, which is somewhat similiar to the markup in Android. However, when a client wants to visit your web-page they will need to use a plugin to view it.

Silverlight:
https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

Flash:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash.html

Also, consider who your client is. Is it an internal webpage just for you? Or is it a public web page? If it's a page just for you then you can use 3rd-party platforms like Flash or Silverlight. But if it's a public web page you really should reconsider using HTML.

**Update:**

You may also want to take a look at [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/). It is supported by the "common browsers". From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly):

> [...] it provides a
>   way to run code written in multiple languages on the web at near
>   native speed, with client apps running on the web that previously
>   couldn’t have done so.